# unable to link Intel TBB library with libtbb in /usr/lib

Tags: c++, tbb

I downloaded the pre built headers and libraries for Intel TBB from Intel's TBB website. I updated ldconfig to add the tbb shared library to /usr/lib. However on compiling with -tbb the code using g++ ld returns -1 as it is unable to find libtbb

libtbb.so.2 is present in /usr/lib/

here is my full g++ output

```
g++ hellotbb.cpp  -o htbb -I$HOME/libs/tbb43/include  -v  -ltbb 

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'htbb' '-I' '/home/govind/libs/tbb43/include' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1plus -quiet -v -I /home/govind/libs/tbb43/include -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE hellotbb.cpp -quiet -dumpbase hellotbb.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase hellotbb -version -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccnjmEt3.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/govind/libs/tbb43/include
 /usr/include/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 26a7c0bd346d04102f6aea776e0cccc5
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'htbb' '-I' '/home/govind/libs/tbb43/include' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v -I /home/govind/libs/tbb43/include --64 -o /tmp/ccC9Xpee.o /tmp/ccnjmEt3.s
GNU assembler version 2.24 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'htbb' '-I' '/home/govind/libs/tbb43/include' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o htbb /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. /tmp/ccC9Xpee.o -ltbb -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltbb
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that ld does not detect my tbb library in /usr/lib/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure `libtbb.so` is also present and install [`libtbb-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hu/saucy/amd64/libtbb-dev/filelist) package if needed:

> apt-get install libtbb-dev

BTW, your include files are located in suspicious place. Looks like you mixed installation of TBB binaries and include files from different sources. It can lead to bad problems especially if headers are newer than binaries.

Comment: yes that is what I did. I installed libtbb2-dev and it works perfectly well.

Comment: So I recommend removing `-I$HOME/libs/tbb43/include` from the command line OR use binaries from `$HOME/libs/tbb43` instead of older binaries in `/usr/lib`. And please don't forget to upvote/accept the answer ;)